# Kafka pattern subscription. Rebalancing is not being triggered on new topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

According to the documentation on [kafka javadocs](http://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#subscribe(java.util.regex.Pattern,%20org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRebalanceListener)) if I:

- Subscribe to a pattern
- Create a topic that matches the pattern

A rebalance should occur, which makes the consumer read from that new topic. But that's not happening.

If I stop and start the consumer, it does pick up the new topic. So I know the new topic matches the pattern. There's a possible duplicate of this question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37120537/whitelist-filter-in-kafka-doesnt-pick-up-new-topics but that question got nowhere.

I'm seeing the kafka logs and there are no errors, it just doesn't trigger a rebalance. The rebalance is triggered when consumers join or die, but not when new topics are created (not even when partitions are added to existing topics, but that's another subject).

I'm using kafka 0.10.0.0, and the official Java client for the "New Consumer API", meaning broker GroupCoordinator instead of fat client + zookeeper.

This is the code for the sample consumer:

```
public class SampleConsumer {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer;
    try (InputStream props = Resources.getResource("consumer.props").openStream()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(props);
        properties.setProperty("group.id", "my-group");

        System.out.println(properties.get("group.id"));
        consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
    }
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("mytopic.+");
    consumer.subscribe(pattern, new SampleRebalanceListener());
    while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(1000);
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
            System.out.printf("%s %s\n", record.topic(), record.value());
        }
    }
}
```

}

In the producer, I'm sending messages to topics named mytopic1, mytopic2, etc.

Patterns are pretty much useless if the rebalance is not triggered.

Do you know why the rebalance is not happening?

Comment: How long did you wait to see if the new topic started being consumed? The group coordinator broker asynchronously checks to see if new topics match the pattern, and it does so periodically. It's possible you didn't wait long enough.

Comment: @alexlod your comment was in the right direction. I found which property controls the period time for the check and added it to an answer.

Answer (score 12):

The documentation mentions "The pattern matching will be done periodically against topics existing at the time of check.". It turns out the "periodically" corresponds to the metadata.max.age.ms property. By setting that property (inside "consumer.props" in my code sample) to i.e. 5000 I can see it detects new topics and partitions every 5 seconds.

This is as designed, according to this jira ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3854:

> The final note on the JIRA stating that a later created topic that matches a consumer's subscription pattern would not be assigned to the consumer upon creation seems to be as designed. A repeat subscribe() to the same pattern would be needed to handle that case.

The refresh metadata polling does the "repeat subscribe()" mentioned in the ticket.

This is confusing coming from Kafka 0.8 where there was true triggering based on zookeper watches, instead of polling. IMO 0.9 is more of a downgrade for this scenario, instead of "just in time" rebalancing, this becomes either high frequency polling with overhead, or low frequency polling with long times before it reacts to new topics/partitions.

Answer (score -1):

to trigger a rebalance immediately, you can explicitly make a poll call after subscribe to the topic:

```
kafkaConsumer.poll(pollDuration);
```

refer to:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-568%3A+Explicit+rebalance+triggering+on+the+Consumer

Comment: This will join a group and rebalance, yes, but will not immediately find new topics after the first poll

Answer (score -2):

In your consumer code, use the following:

```
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, EARLIEST)
```

and try again

Comment: AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG is about a completely different aspect of kafka