# Kafka Topic Refresh Rate for Topic patterns

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

How often does kafka consumer refresh the topic list? Is there any property to set this interval? I am using subscribe() call with topic Pattern to subscribe to topics and I want to keep refreshing the topicList so that when any new topic is added that matches the Pattern, it can be subscribed to.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: set `metadata.max.age.ms` in your consumer. For a longer answer, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38833347/1046859